# Read and extract data from a ShapeFile with Java

Tags: java, shapefile

After several days of research and testing to read and extract data from a shapefile
I am able to read the file and store it in a ShapefileDataStore (with the geotools library):

```
String filePath  = "export_sig.shp";
File file = new File(filePath);     
ShapefileDataStore dataStore = new ShapefileDataStore(file.toURL());
```

I tried several scripts found on the internet like:

```
File inFile = new File("export_sig.shp");

// Read
DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(
        Collections.singletonMap("url", inFile.toURI().toURL()));

String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);

FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
        source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource(inputTypeName);

FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
        inputFeatureCollection = source.getFeatures();
```

he always hangs on:

```
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = (SimpleFeatureSource) dataStore.getFeatureSource(dataStore.getTypeNames()[0]);
```

with error message :

```
    AVERTISSEMENT: ╔chec lors de l'initialisation d'un service de catÚgorie "CRSFactory". La cause est "ServiceConfigurationError: org (...) could not be instantiated".
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.crs.CRSFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.scanForPlugins(FactoryRegistry.java:564)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.safeScanForPlugins(FactoryRegistry.java:540)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:175)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:117)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:275)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:254)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:115)
        at org.geotools.referencing.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:212)
        at org.geotools.referencing.FactoryFinder.getCRSFactory(FactoryFinder.java:322)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.prj.PrjFileReader.<init>(PrjFileReader.java:69)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.openPrjReader(ShapefileDataStore.java:535)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.readAttributes(ShapefileDataStore.java:676)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getSchema(ShapefileDataStore.java:626)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getSchema(ShapefileDataStore.java:620)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getFeatureSource(ShapefileDataStore.java:927)
        at fr.brgm.cm.web.GeometriesController.importerResultShape(GeometriesController.java:240)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:122)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$100(MethodReference.java:44)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:105)
        at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:68)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:196)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:212)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
        at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.geotools.util.WeakHashSet.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
        at org.geotools.util.CanonicalSet.<init>(CanonicalSet.java:68)
        at org.geotools.util.CanonicalSet.newInstance(CanonicalSet.java:81)
        at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory.<init>(ReferencingObjectFactory.java:115)
        at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory.<init>(ReferencingObjectFactory.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 119 more

mai 04, 2018 11:45:41 AM FactoryRegistry scanForPlugins
AVERTISSEMENT: ╔chec lors de l'initialisation d'un service de catÚgorie "DatumFactory". La cause est "ServiceConfigurationError: org (...) could not be instantiated".
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.opengis.referencing.datum.DatumFactory: Provider org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.scanForPlugins(FactoryRegistry.java:564)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.safeScanForPlugins(FactoryRegistry.java:540)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:175)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:117)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:275)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProvider(FactoryRegistry.java:254)
        at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.getServiceProvider(FactoryCreator.java:115)
        at org.geotools.referencing.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:212)
        at org.geotools.referencing.FactoryFinder.getDatumFactory(FactoryFinder.java:252)
        at org.geotools.referencing.factory.GeotoolsFactory.createFromWKT(GeotoolsFactory.java:1121)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.prj.PrjFileReader.<init>(PrjFileReader.java:69)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.openPrjReader(ShapefileDataStore.java:535)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.readAttributes(ShapefileDataStore.java:676)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getSchema(ShapefileDataStore.java:626)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getSchema(ShapefileDataStore.java:620)
        at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore.getFeatureSource(ShapefileDataStore.java:927)
        at fr.brgm.cm.web.GeometriesController.importerResultShape(GeometriesController.java:240)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:63)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:122)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$100(MethodReference.java:44)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:258)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:84)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:114)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:105)
        at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
        at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
        at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:68)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:196)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:212)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
        at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.bufferAndPostProcess(ContentBufferingFilter.java:169)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.contentfilter.ContentBufferingFilter.doFilter(ContentBufferingFilter.java:126)
        at org.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:120)
        at org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter.java:163)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
```

there my dependancy :

```
<dependency>


 <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt2-shapefile -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt2-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>          
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I want to recover from my shapefile is data (date, ids, geometry ...) after I'm going to control them and injected them

any help please :(